# Add a new step between cart and checkout in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

Is there any way to add a new step between cart and checkout in WooCommerce?

I wanted to add a new step called (mode) between cart and checkout on woocommerce

---

Edit:

I have 4 steps, when I click on the button to pass into the 2 step then it doesn't, it just redirect me into a new page (custom page)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need first to add a new page in WordPress for your custom Step. Then the code below will replace the button name and link in cart page. You will have to set in this code the desired button name and link to your custom page on both buttons (cart page and Minicart widget too)

```
// For cart page: replacing proceed to checkout button
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'change_proceed_to_checkout', 1 );
function change_proceed_to_checkout() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'custom_button_proceed_to_custom_page', 20 );
}

// For mini Cart widget: Replace checkout button
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'change_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart', 1 );
function change_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'custom_button_to_custom_page', 20 );
}

// Cart page: Displays the replacement custom button linked to your custom page
function custom_button_proceed_to_custom_page() {
    $button_name = esc_html__( 'Custom page step', 'woocommerce' ); // <== button Name
    $button_link = get_permalink( 168 ); // <== Set here the page ID or use home_url() function
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $button_link;?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">
        <?php echo $button_name; ?>
    </a>
    <?php
}
// Mini cart:  Displays the replacement custom button linked to your custom page
function custom_button_to_custom_page() {
    $button_name = esc_html__( 'Custom page', 'woocommerce' ); // <== button Name
    $button_link = get_permalink( 168 ); // <== Set here the page ID or use home_url() function
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $button_link;?>" class="checkout button wc-forward">
        <?php echo $button_name; ?>
    </a>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it worked but not 100% as I wanted, but thanks anyway :)
in my case I have 4 steps, when I click on the button to pass into the 2 step then it doesn't, it just redirect me into a new page (custom page)

Comment: @Simo You should better try to explain that in an update at the end of your question, editing it… as it's not clear...

Comment: @Simo That is not really more explicit. It seems to be a multistep like, maid by a plugin… You need to set yourself the correct url (or the correct behavior) in the button link. Nobody here can do it for you  or guess what you should need to make it work. My answer here answers your initial question and should be accepted as it works.

Comment: You might need to refresh your permalinks and empty your cart and refill it to get things refreshed and working. After that these snippets worked perfectly for me! Thnx for the answer